# Change language in Grails JavaMelody plugin

Tags: grails, java-melody

I have installed [Grails JavaMelody plugin](https://github.com/javamelody/grails-melody-plugin). It works properly except the language in my Chrome browser. It uses German and there is no way how to change it to English - not in application nor using get params `?lang=en_US`, `?lang=en`, `?locale=en`. I've also tried to delete all cookies.

When I open the same page in Safari, the language is English. How can you set it for Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language of the javamelody reports depends on the language of the browser.
So you can set English as the first language in the Chrome Parameters menu.

Otherwise, you could fix the locale of the reports whatever the browser's language, by using the javamelody parameter `locale`.
For doing that in Grails, you can add in your `grails-app/conf/application.yml`, for example:

```
javamelody:
    locale: en_US
```

Comment: Awesome, the problem settings doesn't work for me. But the grails config works great!